# Any way to flatten multiple nested create foreach loops to a bulk create/insert?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a situation where I am trying to improve performance on a bunch of creates inside nested foreach loops.  It is for creating work orders.  Any number of properties, vendors and work order items/costs can be added before generating the work orders.  A work order will get generated for each property/vendor added, so all selected vendors will have a work order created for them for each property.  If too many are added, that can become quite a mess.  Unfortunately these are how the client wants the system to operate, so I can't redesign it (or it would have been already).

The code is simplified as only the relevant parts are included -

```
DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

foreach (Property property in properties)
{
    foreach (Vendor vendor in vendors)
    {
        WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder();
        WorkOrder.PropertyID = property.PropertyID;
        WorkOrder.VendorID = vendor.VendorID;
        dbContext.AddObject(wo);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();

        foreach (WorkOrderItemViewModel itemView in workOrderItemViewModels)
        {
            WorkOrderItem item = new WorkOrderItem();
            item.WorkOrderID = wo.WorkOrderID;
            dbContext.AddObject(item);
            dbContext.SaveChanges();

            foreach (WorkOrderItemCostViewModel costView in workOrderItemCostViewModels)
            {
                WorkOrderItemCost cost = new WorkOrderItemCost();
                cost.WorkOrderItemID = item.WorkOrderItemID;
                dbContext.AddObject(cost);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That's a lot of nested creates.  It can take a long time if they add too many things to the work orders.  At just 2 objects a piece, it translates to:

2 properties x 2 vendors = 4 work orders

2 work order items x 4 work orders = 8 work order items

2 item costs x 8 work order items = 16 item costs

grand total = 28 creates

The problem is I need the IDs from the previous objects for the current one.  So they need to be created before I can create the next object. I've looked at some solutions - such as SQLite or a bulk insert.... but it looks like they all need to be in a standard sql string format.  I've tried researching to see if you can output the linq to entities generated sql query to a string, but I've not found anything useful.

Is there any good way to rewrite this inside the client's specs to get a much needed performance increase?

Comment: Yes, See [Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx)

Comment: There has to be only one `SaveChanges()` and it should be out side of the for loops.

Comment: I still do not understand about "SQLite or a bulk insert.... but it looks like they all need to be in a standard sql string format" I don't think BulkInsert will have any problem. You can use it outside every loop as a last procedure to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dbContext.SaveChanges();` only one time will optimize performance.

Use this instead:

```
DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();
foreach (Property property in properties)
{
    foreach (Vendor vendor in vendors)
    {
         WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder();
         WorkOrder.PropertyID = property.PropertyID;
         WorkOrder.VendorID = vendor.VendorID;
         dbContext.AddObject(wo);
         foreach (WorkOrderItemViewModel itemView in workOrderItemViewModels)
         {
             WorkOrderItem item = new WorkOrderItem();
             item.WorkOrderID = wo.WorkOrderID;
             dbContext.AddObject(item);
             foreach (WorkOrderItemCostViewModel costView in workOrderItemCostViewModels) 
             {
                 WorkOrderItemCost cost = new WorkOrderItemCost();
                 cost.WorkOrderItemID = item.WorkOrderItemID;
                 dbContext.AddObject(cost);
             }
         }
     }
}
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This did not work for me, however, it looks to be related to some custom code and not actually an issue with the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.  I did not think this would work as I didn't think the primary keys would get populated into the models after creation/saving changes (but they do) -  here it is (and pretty simple):

```
DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();
List<WorkOrder> workOrders = new List<WorkOrder>();
List<WorkOrderItem> workOrderItems = new List<WorkOrderItem>();

foreach (Property property in properties)
{
    foreach (Vendor vendor in vendors)
    {
        WorkOrder wo = new WorkOrder();
        WorkOrder.PropertyID = property.PropertyID;
        WorkOrder.VendorID = vendor.VendorID;
        dbContext.AddObject(wo);
        workOrders.Add(wo);
    }
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();

foreach (WorkOrder wo in workOrders)
{
    foreach (WorkOrderItemViewModel itemView in workOrderItemViewModels)
    {
        WorkOrderItem item = new WorkOrderItem();
        item.WorkOrderID = wo.WorkOrderID;
        dbContext.AddObject(item);
        workOrderItems.Add(item);
    }
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();

foreach (WorkOrderItem item in workOrderItems)
{
    foreach (WorkOrderItemCostViewModel costView in workOrderItemCostViewModels)
    {
        WorkOrderItemCost cost = new WorkOrderItemCost();
        cost.WorkOrderItemID = item.WorkOrderItemID;
        dbContext.AddObject(cost);
    }
}

dbContext.SaveChanges();
```